# pix2pixHD shows error after changing datasets

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I was trying out the pix2pixHD code from the link below.
https://github.com/NVIDIA/pix2pixHD

The train.py worked with default images (in datasets/cityscapes). However, after changing images in the dataset, it shows the error below.

```
    model [Pix2PixHDModel] was created
    create web directory ./checkpoints/label2city/web...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/shimada/venv/py2.7/projects/Hiwi/pix2pixHD/train.py", line 58, in <module>
        Variable(data['image']), Variable(data['feat']), infer=save_fake)
      File "/home/shimada/venv/py2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 325, in __call__
        result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
      File "/home/shimada/venv/py2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 66, in forward
        return self.module(*inputs[0], **kwargs[0])
      File "/home/shimada/venv/py2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 325, in __call__
        result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
      File "/home/shimada/venv/py2.7/projects/Hiwi/pix2pixHD/models/pix2pixHD_model.py", line 141, in forward
        fake_image = self.netG.forward(input_concat)
      File "/home/shimada/venv/py2.7/projects/Hiwi/pix2pixHD/models/networks.py", line 213, in forward
        return self.model(input)             
      File "/home/shimada/venv/py2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 325, in __call__
        result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
      File "/home/shimada/venv/py2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 67, in forward
        input = module(input)
      File "/home/shimada/venv/py2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 325, in __call__
        result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
      File "/home/shimada/venv/py2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 277, in forward
        self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
      File "/home/shimada/venv/py2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 90, in conv2d
        return f(input, weight, bias)
    RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight[64, 36, 7, 7], so expected input[1, 39, 518, 1030] to have 36 channels, but got 39 channels instead
    THCudaCheck FAIL file=/pytorch/torch/lib/THC/generic/THCStorage.c line=184 error=59 : device-side assert triggered
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
      what():  cuda runtime error (59) : device-side assert triggered at /pytorch/torch/lib/THC/generic/THCStorage.c:184
    bash: line 1: 10965 Aborted                 (core dumped) env "PYCHARM_HOSTED"="1" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED"="1" "PYTHONIOENCODING"="UTF-8" "PYCHARM_MATPLOTLIB_PORT"="42188" "JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN"="1" "PYTHONPATH"="/home/shimada/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend:/home/shimada/venv/py2.7/projects/Hiwi/pix2pixHD" /home/shimada/venv/py2.7/bin/python -u /home/shimada/venv/py2.7/projects/Hiwi/pix2pixHD/train.py
```

I changed the images with same size (width 2048, hight 1024), same extension (.png) and gave the same names. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I think it is telling you that size of some variable are not expected.

Comment: yes, but I changed only the training images, and the image size is completely the same. So, I don't understand what affected the variable sizes...

Comment: @soshishimada Which shell script did you run to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your original image/ground truth data is grayscale. In that case you have to define `--input_nc 1 --output_nc 1` means grayscale. You also have to change in pix2pixHD code to load grayscale images.